# Mongoid unique combination two keys

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I would like to ask how I can create a combination of unique keys in ruby Mongoid where each key is not unique but they are unique when they are together in one record `(key1+key2).unique`. I need to insert a data in to database but in that way when in database can exist only one record with `(key1+Key2)` combination

Comment: `validates :key1, uniqueness:{scope: :key2}` is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am getting Mongoid validation error by using this code. In Mongodb is method like this `db.collection.ensureIndex( { a: 1, b: 1 }, { unique: true } )` is any similar methods in Mongoid?

Comment: I just found ansver `index({ ssn: 1 }, { unique: true, drop_dups: true })` Thank you!

Comment: Not sure I understand the Issue because the [Docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/validation.html) state that validation scoping like this is appropriate. Glad you found an answer for yourself though. It is always better that way.

Comment: looks like when I use this code `index({ a: 1, b: 1 }, { unique: true, drop_dups: true })` it just dose not do anything